# vue/multi-word-component-names rule cannot be disabled from EsLint

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

Problem:

```js
[eslint] 
[redacted]/components/Settings.vue
  1:1  error  Component name "Settings" should always be multi-word  vue/multi-word-component-names
```

There is no Settings.vue at all!

```bash
❯ tree -I 'node_modules|public|assets'

.
├── README.md
├── babel.config.js
├── jsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── App.vue
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── HomePage.vue
│   │   ├── SettingsPage.vue
│   │   └── TopBar.vue
│   ├── global.css
│   └── main.js
├── tailwind.config.js
├── vue.config.js
└── yarn.lock
```

SettingsPage is not even Settings!

```js
/* eslint-disable vue/multi-word-component-names */
  
<script>
import TopBar from "./TopBar.vue";

export default {
    name: 'SettingsPage',
```

My EsLint config did not want you at all!

```js
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true,
    },
    extends: [
        'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
        'eslint:recommended',
    ],
    rules: {
        // Other rules...
        'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off'
    },
};
```

I even kicked you off at the top of my file!

```js
/* eslint-disable vue/multi-word-component-names */
```

Deleted node_modules, reinstalled it again, didnt work.

Deleted yarn cache, didnt work.

Anger I feel is immeasurable, as if JavaScript was a 10/10, flawless, perfect language, Vue is enforcing this rule, which, isnt even a real error right now! What to do? What does EsLint want from me?

Comment: Iv had this and it is anoyying have you tried clearing eslint cache ? `rm .eslintcache` + `npx eslint --no-cache .`

Comment: There is no eslintcache in frontend directory. Ran second command, then `yarn serve`, same error.

Comment: Maybe create the random settings.vue file then see if the error goes away and then delete it

Comment: Same error, unfortunately. Restarted dev server after creation / deletion, and, yes, same.